Google Maps Flutter is not working smooth using AndroidMapRenderer.latest
I am using google_maps_flutter and when I am using recommended renderer latest my map is working like it is lagging.
Screen recording
It's release on my personal phone, so I expect this to work smoothly.
I tried using AndroidMapRenderer.legacy but it's not recommended and also it's have other issues
I wonder why is that happening, I thought that maybe is my custom markers, but as you can see with default marker it's still not smooth.
Flutter version: 3.22.0
Here is my code for maps:
GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: (state as MapsStateCompleted).mapMarkers.first.position,
                    zoom: 10,
                  ),
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  markers: state.mapMarkers,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    if (!_controller.isCompleted) {
                      context.read<MapsCubit>().initMapController(controller);
                    }
                  },
                )

